# Modify daterangepicker to only show "Date range"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I found daterangepicker ( http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/ ) and am trying to customize it.

Does anyone know how to remove "Last 7 days", "Month to date", "Year to date", etc..?

I just want to see the "Date range" in the dropdown menu.

Thanks.

MODIFIED: (oops)
What I meant was, is there a way to get it to go directly to "Date range" and bypass the dropdown menu without showing all the other options?

Answer (score 1):

`presets` and `presetRanges` parameters will do what you want. Use them in constructor:

```
$('input').daterangepicker({
    presetRanges: [],
    presets: { dateRange: "Date Range" }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, that indeed works. I realized that I didn't ask the correct question. How would I go directly to the "Date Range" and bypass the dropdown menu entirely?

Comment: I think you should specify exactly one preset range with desired data, read the documentation - it has an example of creating presetRanges

Answer (score 1):

I've done it this way:

```
$('input#date').daterangepicker({
    onOpen: function(){
        $('a', $('.ui-daterangepicker-dateRange:visible').not('.ui-state-active')).each(function(){
            $(this).trigger('click')
        })
        $('ul.ui-widget-content').hide()
    }
})
```

It hides left menu, and also auto-opens the `Date range` item.

Comment: +1 Works great, thanks. Used for my admin interface that requires date range.